# What is the difference between AWS Amplify and the "Applications" feature within AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

AWS Amplify and the "Applications" feature within AWS Lambda seem to have a few things in common:

- Both seem to be a wrapper around several AWS resources
- Both walk you through a guided setup to provision a working AWS stack
- Both set up some CI/CD pipelines for you so that Git commits trigger a build and deploy

So what are the differences between these two services, and what are some scenarios where you might want to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

**AWS Amplify** is a toolchain for front-end developers to interact with AWS resources. It provides a cli program to manage resources and (JS/Android/iOS) libraries to integrate them into your front-end applications.
It doesn't 'wrap' resources, but is merely a convenience layer to manage them (it is somewhat similar to AWS SAM); Amplify generates CloudFormation templates, stores those locally, and uses `aws-cli` to provision them. Note that Amplify can also be used *just as a front-end library* to integrate resources that are already set up.

**AWS Lambda Applications** is an actual AWS service, or rather a feature of AWS Lambda. It groups related resources, so they can be managed and deployed as if it was a single resource.

> ... what are
> some scenarios where you might want to choose one over the other?

Amplify is aimed at web- and mobile developers: it allows them to manage backend resources without much backend knowledge.

It is not a matter of 'using one over the other'; they can actually be used in conjunction with each other.